# How to convert csv file to LIBSVM format using Java

Tags: java, python, c, svm, libsvm

According to http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#f307
data can be converted to LIBSVM format by using MATLAB/OCTAVE interface or a C code that it provided. And in my Google searches you can also convert to LIBSVM format in Python.

But I'm creating a java desktop app that can convert a CSV to LIBSVM format.

Does anyone know the shortest way to integrate either MATLAB/OCTAVE/the C code provided/ Python to a Java application? Is there a plugin for these that I can run them in java?

Comment: Please show some code what you have tried.

Comment: the c code they provided is here: http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faqfiles/convert.c